# Missing Neovim RubyGem

Tags: neovim

I've just installed neovim and I have problem with RubyGem.

Output of `:CheckHealth` indicates missing neovim RubyGem:

```
## Ruby provider
  - ERROR: Missing Neovim RubyGem
      - SUGGESTIONS:
        - Install or upgrade the neovim RubyGem using `gem install neovim`.
  - INFO: Ruby Version: ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]
  - INFO: Host Executable: not found
  - INFO: Host Version: not found
```

After installing `sudo gem install neovim`:

```
Successfully installed neovim-0.3.1
Parsing documentation for neovim-0.3.1
Done installing documentation for neovim after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

The output of `:CheckHealth` is the same as before:

```
## Ruby provider
  - ERROR: Missing Neovim RubyGem
      - SUGGESTIONS:
        - Install or upgrade the neovim RubyGem using `gem install neovim`.
  - INFO: Ruby Version: ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]
  - INFO: Host Executable: not found
  - INFO: Host Version: not found
```

Am I missing something? How can I fix this problem?

```
:echo has('ruby') returns 1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the PATH of installed gems into your PATH.

You can do it like below in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or other shells' rc/profile files.

```
[ -d $HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin ] && PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:$PATH
```

`export PATH` together with all other PATH values.

Comment: Not sure if `sudo gem install ..` installs to `~/.gem`, but the `sudo` probably isn't required in the first place.

Comment: `sudo` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, on OpenSUSE that the binary file is renamed when installing the gem. So on my computer I need to set have this line in my `init.vim`

`let g:ruby_host_prog="/usr/bin/neovim-ruby-host.ruby2.4"`